# How does planned cattle grazing compare with other methods (like carbon capture) of mitigating climate change?

Tags: climate-change, ecology

I recently saw a great [talk](https://www.ted.com/talks/allan_savory_how_to_green_the_world_s_deserts_and_reverse_climate_change) by Allan Savory, the pioneering ecologist about holistic management of cattle grazing to prevent desertification of grasslands. He claimed that it is the only viable way for mitigating damages due to climate change. Is this claim supported by scientific studies in this area and how does it compare with methods like carbon capture and storage?